# Shopify Infinite scroll has stopped product Quick View and Quick Add to Cart buttons from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, infinite-scroll

I am using Shopify "Empire Theme" with quick product view and quick add to cart button and recently I added infinite scroll to products on each collection using Ajaxinate.js.

When I open a collection page it loads with some products which is supposed to do, The products already there work fine with quick view and quick add to cart and also.

The Infinite scroll works fine and it loads new product fine but the problem is raised  when the new products loaded through AJAX call doesnt have quick add to cart and quick view function.

In short the product which are loaded with AJAX call dont have Quick View and add to cart function on other hand the product which are  not loaded with AJAX and are already there have the above mentioned functionalities.

If you want to see the store here is the link. Check the first 8 products you will see they work fine, both the + icon (add item to cart) and the quick view is fine too. But after 8 items nothing works.

https://www.gyftss.myshopify.com

password: 1239

Code for Ajax infinite scroll is:

```
'use strict';

/* ===================================================================================== @preserve =
 ___  _   _    _
/   || | | |  | |
\__  | | | |  | |  __
/    |/  |/_) |/  /  \_/\/
\___/|__/| \_/|__/\__/  /\_/
              |\
              |/
Ajaxinate
version v2.0.6
https://github.com/Elkfox/Ajaxinate
Copyright (c) 2017 Elkfox Co Pty Ltd
https://elkfox.com
MIT License
================================================================================================= */

var Ajaxinate = function ajaxinateConstructor(config) {
  var settings = config || {};
  /*
    pagination: Selector of pagination container
    method: [options are 'scroll', 'click']
    container: Selector of repeating content
    offset: 0, offset the number of pixels before the bottom to start loading more on scroll
    loadingText: 'Loading', The text changed during loading
    callback: null, function to callback after a new page is loaded
  */
  var defaultSettings = {
    pagination: '.AjaxinatePagination',
    method: 'scroll',
    container: '.AjaxinateLoop',
    offset: 660,
    loadingText: '<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/5072/4415/files/spinner.gif?16236020128462925067" style="width:40px">',
    callback: null
  };
  // Merge configs
  this.settings = Object.assign(defaultSettings, settings);

  // Bind 'this' to applicable prototype functions
  this.addScrollListeners = this.addScrollListeners.bind(this);
  this.addClickListener = this.addClickListener.bind(this);
  this.checkIfPaginationInView = this.checkIfPaginationInView.bind(this);
  this.stopMultipleClicks = this.stopMultipleClicks.bind(this);
  this.destroy = this.destroy.bind(this);

  // Set up our element selectors
  this.containerElement = document.querySelector(this.settings.container);
  this.paginationElement = document.querySelector(this.settings.pagination);

  this.initialize();
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.initialize = function initializeTheCorrectFunctionsBasedOnTheMethod() {
  // Find and initialise the correct function based on the method set in the config
  if (this.containerElement) {
    var initializers = {
      click: this.addClickListener,
      scroll: this.addScrollListeners
    };
    initializers[this.settings.method]();
  }
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.addScrollListeners = function addEventListenersForScrolling() {
  if (this.paginationElement) {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkIfPaginationInView);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.checkIfPaginationInView);
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.checkIfPaginationInView);
  }
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.addClickListener = function addEventListenerForClicking() {
  if (this.paginationElement) {
    this.nextPageLinkElement = this.paginationElement.querySelector('a');
    this.clickActive = true;
    if (typeof this.nextPageLinkElement !== 'undefined') {
      this.nextPageLinkElement.addEventListener('click', this.stopMultipleClicks);
    }
  }
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.stopMultipleClicks = function handleClickEvent(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.clickActive) {
    this.nextPageLinkElement.innerHTML = this.settings.loadingText;
    this.nextPageUrl = this.nextPageLinkElement.href;
    this.clickActive = false;
    this.loadMore();
  }
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.checkIfPaginationInView = function handleScrollEvent() {
  var top = this.paginationElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - this.settings.offset;
  var bottom = this.paginationElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + this.settings.offset;
  if (top <= window.innerHeight && bottom >= 0) {
    this.nextPageLinkElement = this.paginationElement.querySelector('a');
    this.removeScrollListener();
    if (this.nextPageLinkElement) {
      this.nextPageLinkElement.innerHTML = this.settings.loadingText;
      this.nextPageUrl = this.nextPageLinkElement.href;
      this.loadMore();
    }
  }
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.loadMore = function getTheHtmlOfTheNextPageWithAnAjaxRequest() {
  this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  this.request.onreadystatechange = function success() {
    if (this.request.readyState === 4 && this.request.status === 200) {
      var newContainer = this.request.responseXML.querySelectorAll(this.settings.container)[0];
      var newPagination = this.request.responseXML.querySelectorAll(this.settings.pagination)[0];
      this.containerElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newContainer.innerHTML);
      this.paginationElement.innerHTML = newPagination.innerHTML;
      if (this.settings.callback && typeof this.settings.callback === 'function') {
        this.settings.callback(this.request.responseXML);
      }
      this.initialize();
    }
  }.bind(this);
  this.request.open('GET', this.nextPageUrl);
  this.request.responseType = 'document';
  this.request.send();
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.removeClickListener = function removeClickEventListener() {
  this.nextPageLinkElement.addEventListener('click', this.stopMultipleClicks);
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.removeScrollListener = function removeScrollEventListener() {
  document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.checkIfPaginationInView);
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.checkIfPaginationInView);
  window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', this.checkIfPaginationInView);
};

Ajaxinate.prototype.destroy = function removeEventListenersAndReturnThis() {
  // This method is used to unbind event listeners from the DOM
  // This function is called manually to destroy "this" Ajaxinate instance
  var destroyers = {
    click: this.removeClickListener,
    scroll: this.removeScrollListener
  };
  destroyers[this.settings.method]();
  return this;
};
```

The initialization Code is:

```
    <script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var endlessScroll = new Ajaxinate();
    offset: 660

});

</script>
```

The theme javascript file for theme can be found here:

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0066/5072/4415/t/5/assets/empire.js?11964077371852938126

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without looking too much in the code it pretty much sounds that the events are not delegated at all, meaning that new products loaded via AJAX will not have any JS events applied to them and they will not just work. You will need to delegate all the required events, but since this is a premium theme... good luck with the code.

Answer (score 0):

With this code I was able to solve the quick look of the theme empire

```html
<script>
var empire_js_o = '<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1540/2631/t/34/assets/empire.js?9521252849869083980" data-scripts="" data-shopify-api-url="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/themes_support/api.jquery-0ea851da22ae87c0290f4eeb24bc8b513ca182f3eb721d147c009ae0f5ce14f9.js" data-shopify-currencies="//cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js" data-shopify-countries="/services/javascripts/countries.js" data-shopify-common="//cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/themes_support/shopify_common-040322ee69221c50a47032355f2f7e6cbae505567e2157d53dfb0a2e7701839c.js" data-shopify-cart="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1540/2631/t/34/assets/jquery.cart.js?9521252849869083980" id="empire_js">';
    var NewEmpire = function reload_js() {
        $('#empire_js').remove();
        $(empire_js_o).appendTo('head');
    }

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var endlessScroll = new Ajaxinate({
    method: 'scroll',
    loadingText: 'Loading...',
    callback: NewEmpire
  });
});
</script>
```